# Remove entire row from table with HTML::TableExtract

Tags: html, perl, html-table

Is there a way to remove an entire row (html tags 'n all) from an HTML Table with `HTML::TableExtract`?

Mucking around with the sample code from CPAN, this is what I've tried so far:

```
use HTML::TableExtract qw(tree);

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( headers => [qw(name type members)] );

# get $html_string out of a file...

$te->parse($html_string);

my $table = $te->first_table_found();
my $table_tree = $table->tree;
$table_tree->row(4)->replace_content('');
my $document_tree = $te->tree;
my $document_html = $document_tree->as_HTML;

# write $document_html to a file ...
```

Now, as the name suggests, 'replace_content()' in the line `$table_tree->row(4)->replace_content('');` removes the *content* of row 4, but the row itself remains in markup. I need to get the  tags and everything in-between removed as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the `parent` and `delete` methods

See the docs for [HTML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/~jfearn/HTML-Tree-4.2/lib/HTML/Element.pm) and for [HTML::Element::delete](http://search.cpan.org/~jfearn/HTML-Tree-4.2/lib/HTML/Element.pm#%24h-%3Edetach%28%29)

**UPDATE**

Ok, click that checkmark and mark this one as answered....Here it is:

```
my($p) = $table_tree->row(4)->parent();
$p->delete;
```

Also, **NOTE**, you need the () parens around $p!  If you don't have parens don't get back a reference.

For me, with the above Perl code working on this HTML,

```
<table>
   <tr><td>name</td><td>type</td><td>members</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row1</td><td>row1</td> <td>row1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row2</td><td>row2</td> <td>row2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row3</td><td>row3</td> <td>row3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row4</td><td>row4</td> <td>row4</td></tr>
</table>
```

I get this as a result of printing `$document_html`

```
<table>
   <tr><td>name</td><td>type</td><td>members</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row1</td><td>row1</td><td>row1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row2</td><td>row2</td><td>row2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>row3</td><td>row3</td><td>row3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Notice that there is no empty `<tr></tr>`

Comment: Thanks Mark. I guess I didn't drill down deep enough into the classes. I was just trying out [delete()](http://search.cpan.org/~jfearn/HTML-Tree-4.2/lib/HTML/Element.pm#$h-%3Edelete%28%29_destroy_destroy_content) as well. But both `detach` and `delete` still leave the empty row `<tr></tr>` in the markup. Still far better than what I had before though.

Comment: Selected as answer. [@Mark Koopman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/766921/mark-koopman) rocks! :)